# Check if list element is visible (jquery.visible)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visible

I'm trying to check if each element of an `ul` list is visible using the `jquery.visible plugin`. The problem is that the script does not handle each `"li"` element as independent, so putting this:

```
var element = $("ul li");

if (element.visible(true)) {
    element.removeClass("hidden");
}
```

Removes the "hidden" class of all elements at the same time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `each` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing `element` as an array, so the name is misleading, and it may be throwing you off later in the code.

You want something like this (untested):

```
var arrElements = $("ul li");

arrElements.each(function() {
    if ($(this).visible(true)) {
        $(this).removeClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

Note that I am using the `each` method and `$(this)` to act on only one `li` element at a time.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking just the css property:

```
 if(element.css('display') != 'none')
```